# How to iterate through memory block (created with malloc) in C?

Tags: c, sorting, memory, malloc, block

My objective is to read an unknown amount of integers from a text file, store them into a block of memory, sort them, and output to a new file. I have a program that can read integers from a file and output them, and now I'm trying to implement the sorting part. I'm coming into this class with an arts background, and my professor's instructions on how to use it are unclear to me.

Instructions: Use malloc() to assign a memory block to an integer pointer. Then each time a new integer is read from the input file and the current memory block is not enough to hold it, use realloc() to assign more space to the memory block so as to hold more integers. You may use *(ptr+x) (an equivalent way is to use ptr[x]) to access the (x+1)th integer in the memory block pointed by the integer pointer ptr. You may then apply any sorting algorithm (e.g., selection sort or bubble sort) you've learned in your previous courses to sort these integers.

What I'm not understanding is how to iterate through an allocated memory block in order to sort it. What is this x my professor mentions? If you could clarify how to use this? I don't want to post my code to avoid cheating. Thanks!

Comment: So, posting your code might be cheating but us posting code wouldn't be?

Comment: Do you want to know how to sort an array of `int`, or how to use `*(ptr+x)` and `ptr[x]`?

Comment: `x` is a variable in the mathematical sense. Your professsor customarily omits the implicit "for any number x" preamble.

Comment: We don't want to post code either to avoid cheating. Unfortunately it is not clear what problem you have with writing code to provide any other concrete help... If you are looking for what to do - ask professor/TA for guidance.

Comment: @PC Luddite - I just asked for an explanation, not code.

Comment: I don't understand what this generic "x" stands for. What is it referencing? We're not working with arrays. is x the length of an integer in a memory block? Thanks for your help.

Comment: well OP, if you don't want to provide C code, then at least provide pseudo code to show your logic. We aren't a homework service.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;   // uninitialized variable (its content is unknown)
int count_of_item = 10 ; // initialized variable
int *ptr=malloc(count_of_item*sizeof(int)); // ptr is an allocated memory block

for(x=0;x<count_of_item;x++) // iterating through the memory block
    printf("%x element =%d\n",x,ptr[x]);// and printing its content
                                         // x is the index in range from
                                         // 0 to count_of_item-1.
```

iterating through an allocated memory block, is accessing its content in order to read it or to make a change on it (write).
this is the basics of 'c' if you are stuck here, you are in troubles.